# Knockout self & this keyword gotach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
    <img src="http://www.aero-sa.com/images/ajax-loader.gif" data-bind="visible:loading" />
var model = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.loading =  ko.observable(true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.loading(false);
    }, 4000);
}
ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

i have few question on the above code. what is `this` keyword here? **this** denote what? when i write the code like then image is not getting hide....why **this** keyword is not working setTimeout.

```
var model = function() {
        //var self = this;
        this.loading =  ko.observable(true);
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.loading(false);
        }, 4000);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

please explain if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309516/when-to-use-self-in-javascript

Comment: `console.log()` is your friend!

Comment: Why did you create a new question while I tried to answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590336/how-to-bind-list-of-images-using-knockout-in-page-with-loading-spinner#comment25602854_17590336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the setTimeout the 'this' context is of **Window** object.
Where as the **this** outsite of setTimeout is of **Model class constructor**.
So you have to use:

```
var self = this;
```

and then inside setTimeout use self instead of this.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to read THIS: 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/

Answer (score 1):

The second `this` is not working because you changed the context where `this` is valid... The second `this` is only valid for properties inside the `setTimeout` function.

This would work:

```
var model = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.loading =  ko.observable(true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.loading(false);
    }, 4000);
}
ko.applyBindings(new model());
```